# Use node in centos, npm run build performs different results for vuejs

Tags: node.js, linux, npm, vue.js, vue-cli

Two user modes，The expected result should be in work mode.But why is it different?

root: `npm run build` results:

```
 static/js/vendor.c30b6cdedd8057510721.js    1.23 MB vendor
```

work: `npm run build` results:

```
static/js/vendor.a26896cc673096a569fa.js     583 kB vendor
```

---

root: `which node -> /bin/node`

work: `which node => /usr/local/bin/node`

node: v8.9.1

npm: 5.5.1

Comment: Maybe the environment is not set to production when you build as root.

Comment: @TGrif Are you talking about NODE_ENV? `npm run build`  time NODE_ENV defaults to production.